# java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'void org.springframework.util.Assert.state(boolean, java.util.function.Supplier)'

Tags: java, spring, maven, unit-testing, junit

I tried to upgrade a project to JDK11 from JDK8, whole part of business logic goes well but when the maven reaches test classes all of them fail with exact same exception
For example

```
 initializationError(com.foo.bar.etc.utils.TimeUtilsTest)  Time elapsed: 0 sec  <<< ERROR!
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'void org.springframework.util.Assert.state(boolean, java.util.function.Supplier)'
        at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.ensureSpringRulesAreNotPresent(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:120)
        at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.<init>(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:141)
        at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringRunner.<init>(SpringRunner.java:49)
        at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedConstructorAccessor6.newInstance(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:490)
        at org.junit.internal.builders.AnnotatedBuilder.buildRunner(AnnotatedBuilder.java:104)
        at org.junit.internal.builders.AnnotatedBuilder.runnerForClass(AnnotatedBuilder.java:86)
        at org.junit.runners.model.RunnerBuilder.safeRunnerForClass(RunnerBuilder.java:59)
        at org.junit.internal.builders.AllDefaultPossibilitiesBuilder.runnerForClass(AllDefaultPossibilitiesBuilder.java:26)
        at org.junit.runners.model.RunnerBuilder.safeRunnerForClass(RunnerBuilder.java:59)
        at org.junit.internal.requests.ClassRequest.getRunner(ClassRequest.java:33)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.execute(JUnit4Provider.java:283)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.executeWithRerun(JUnit4Provider.java:173)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.executeTestSet(JUnit4Provider.java:153)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.invoke(JUnit4Provider.java:128)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.invokeProviderInSameClassLoader(ForkedBooter.java:203)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.runSuitesInProcess(ForkedBooter.java:155)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.main(ForkedBooter.java:103)
```

And once everything is done it just sums up all tests classes with list

```
Tests in error:
  BaseSpringTest.initializationError » NoSuchMethod 'void org.springframework.ut...
  EmailAttachmentDaoImplTest.initializationError » NoSuchMethod 'void org.spring...
  EmailEventDaoImplTest.initializationError » NoSuchMethod 'void org.springframe...
  EmailMappingDaoImplTest.initializationError » NoSuchMethod 'void org.springfra...
  EmailRequestDaoImplTest.initializationError » NoSuchMethod 'void org.springfra...
  EmailWindowsDaoImplTest.initializationError » NoSuchMethod 'void org.springfra...
  ServiceClientDaoImplTest.initializationError » NoSuchMethod 'void org.springfr...
  TemplateContextDaoImplTest.initializationError » NoSuchMethod 'void org.spring...
  TemplateMappingDaoImplTest.initializationError » NoSuchMethod 'void org.spring...
  TemplateMetadataDaoImplTest.initializationError » NoSuchMethod 'void org.sprin...
  VarMetadataDaoImplTest.initializationError » NoSuchMethod 'void org.springfram...
  TemplateContextStorageTest.initializationError » NoSuchMethod 'void org.spring...
  ApiRequestFilterTest.initializationError » NoSuchMethod 'void org.springframew...
  TemplateResolutionServiceTest.initializationError » NoSuchMethod 'void org.spr...
  AwsS3ClientTest.initializationError » NoSuchMethod 'void org.springframework.u...
  TimeUtilsTest.initializationError » NoSuchMethod 'void org.springframework.uti...
```

Can it be an issue with some version? I know that it requires the addition of some jars, or upgrading something more beside JDK to version 11

Tests ran fine on JDK8 btw, I suppose that is an important detail.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The issue was resolved after moving spring-core from version 4 to version 5.
For some unknown reason, all spring jars were version 5 except spring-core, to make it even weirder it is a spring boot app, so the whole bundle of spring jars was version 5 except spring-core.

Comment: Which indicates you are doing strange things in your pom.

Comment: Something forced that to version 4, instead of the regular management. So there must be a dependency in your list of dependencies that does that. However without seeing your actual pom which dependency that was is hard to tell.